# How to get a value from the last inserted row?

Tags: java, database, postgresql, jdbc

Is there some way to get a value from the last inserted row?

I am inserting a row where the PK will automatically increase, and I would like to get this PK. Only the PK is guaranteed to be unique in the table.

I am using Java with a JDBC and PostgreSQL.

Comment: I am using JDBC 4, so the  Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS did not work. I've got this error message: 
    "org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Returning autogenerated keys is not supported." But the PostgresSQL - RETURNING did work.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel How did u add duplicate to this question? This was asked in 2008 the claimed duplicate question was asked on 2009. Its not appropriate no?

Comment: @Haramoz The one I closed to is the canonical duplicate for this question. Age is not an important factor in deciding what the duplicate target is, quality of the answers is.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel ok, clear!

Answer (score 68, accepted):

With PostgreSQL you can do it via the RETURNING keyword:

[PostgresSQL - RETURNING](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/sql-insert.html)

```
INSERT INTO mytable( field_1, field_2,... )
VALUES ( value_1, value_2 ) RETURNING anyfield
```

It will return the value of "anyfield". "anyfield" may be a sequence or not.

To use it with JDBC, do:

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("INSERT ... RETURNING ID");
rs.next();
rs.getInt(1);
```

Comment: Use RETURNING "ID" assuming the name of your PK is ID.

Comment: This is certainly the right SQL method, but the question asked how to do this with JDBC, and the other half of the problem is how to execute the statement. As mentioned in other answers, you either need to use `executeQuery()` (returns a ResultSet) instead of `executeUpdate()` (returns number of rows updated), OR use the `RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` option to activate the ability to call `getGeneratedKeys()` method after calling `executeUpdate()`.

Comment: This works - `ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(sqlQuery)`.

Answer (score 28):

See the API docs for [java.sql.Statement](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html).

Basically, when you call `executeUpdate()` or `executeQuery()`, use the `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` constant.  You can then call `getGeneratedKeys` to get the auto-generated keys of all rows created by that execution. (Assuming your JDBC driver provides it.)

It goes something along the lines of this:

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.execute(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
ResultSet keyset = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
```

Comment: Oh if it were that easy.  Unfortunately this doesn't work unless you have the correct Postgres driver version and even then the ResultSet has *all* of the fields and not just the generated id ones.

Comment: Aye, does not work for PostgreSQL

Comment: As far as I know getGeneratedKeys() works only for the JDBC drivers that implement it. The correct thing would be IMHO to run `dmd = conn.getMetadata()` and then run `dmd.supportsGetGeneratedKeys()` to see whether this capability is supported or not.

Comment: The only column returned in the `getGeneratedKeys()` is a `ROWID` - oracle 11.

Answer (score 17):

If you're using JDBC 3.0, then you can get the value of the PK as soon as you inserted it.

Here's an article that talks about how : https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jdbcnew/

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
// Obtain the generated key that results from the query.
stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO authors " +
                   "(first_name, last_name) " +
                   "VALUES ('George', 'Orwell')",
                   Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
ResultSet rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
if ( rs.next() ) {
    // Retrieve the auto generated key(s).
    int key = rs.getInt(1);
}
```

Comment: Note that this won't work for Oracle (I'm using 10g)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976625/value-from-last-inserted-row-in-db

Comment: work nice with postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4.jar

Answer (score 13):

Since PostgreSQL JDBC driver version [8.4-701](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/changes.html#version_8.4-701) the [`PreparedStatement#getGeneratedKeys()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys%28%29) is finally fully functional. We use it here almost one year in production to our full satisfaction.

In "plain JDBC" the `PreparedStatement` needs to be created as follows to make it to return the keys:

```
statement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

You can download the current JDBC driver version [here](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html#current) (which is at the moment still 8.4-701).

Comment: Does it matter if I use `PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` vs `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS`?

Comment: @csharpfolk: Nope. It's defined in `Statement` and `PreparedStatement extends Statement`. See also its source code and javadoc.

Answer (score 8):

The sequences in postgresql are transaction safe. So you can use the

```
currval(sequence)
```

[Quote:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/interactive/functions-sequence.html)

> currval
>
> > Return the value most recently obtained by nextval for this sequence
> >     in the current session. (An error is
> >     reported if nextval has never been
> >     called for this sequence in this
> >     session.) Notice that because this is
> >     returning a session-local value, it
> >     gives a predictable answer even if
> >     other sessions are executing nextval
> >     meanwhile.

Comment: Isn't it possible that another transaction could change the value of the sequence between his INSERT and his SELECT currval() ? I'm assuming that each of those operations would take place in separate transactions.

Comment: No. that exactly what the currval function is for.

Answer (score 7):

Here is how I solved it, based on the answers here:

```
Connection conn = ConnectToDB(); //ConnectToDB establishes a connection to the database.
String sql = "INSERT INTO \"TableName\"" +
        "(\"Column1\", \"Column2\",\"Column3\",\"Column4\")" +
        "VALUES ('value1',value2, 'value3', 'value4') RETURNING 
         \"TableName\".\"TableId\"";
PreparedStatement prpState = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSet rs = prpState.executeQuery();
if(rs.next()){
      System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `Statement`, go for the following

```
//MY_NUMBER is the column name in the database 
String generatedColumns[] = {"MY_NUMBER"};
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

//String sql holds the insert query
stmt.executeUpdate(sql, generatedColumns);

ResultSet rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();

// The generated id

if(rs.next())
long key = rs.getLong(1);
```

If you are using `PreparedStatement`, go for the following

```
String generatedColumns[] = {"MY_NUMBER"};
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql,generatedColumns);
pstmt.setString(1, "qwerty");

pstmt.execute();
ResultSet rs = pstmt.getGeneratedKeys();
if(rs.next())
long key = rs.getLong(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use sequences in postgres for id columns:

```
INSERT mytable(myid) VALUES (nextval('MySequence'));

SELECT currval('MySequence');
```

currval will return the current value of the sequence in the same session.

(In MS SQL, you would use @@identity or SCOPE_IDENTITY())

Answer (score 1):

```
PreparedStatement stmt = getConnection(PROJECTDB + 2)
    .prepareStatement("INSERT INTO fonts (font_size) VALUES(?) RETURNING fonts.*");
stmt.setString(1, "986");
ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery();
while (res.next()) {
    System.out.println("Generated key: " + res.getLong(1));
    System.out.println("Generated key: " + res.getInt(2));
    System.out.println("Generated key: " + res.getInt(3));
}
stmt.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use SELECT currval('MySequence') - the value gets incremented on inserts that fail.

Comment: So what? He just asked for unique values, not contiguous values (which is an impossible goal in a system with parallel abortable transactions).

Comment: The original question: "Is there some way to get a value from the last inserted row?"

Code that uses currval(seq) to form a SELECT statement for obtaining the last inserted row may fail to produce expected results.

Answer (score 0):

For MyBatis 3.0.4 with Annotations and Postgresql driver 9.0-801.jdbc4 you define an interface method in your Mapper like

```
public interface ObjectiveMapper {

@Select("insert into objectives" +
        " (code,title,description) values" +
        " (#{code}, #{title}, #{description}) returning id")
int insert(Objective anObjective);
```

Note that @Select is used instead of @Insert.

Answer (score 0):

for example:

```
 Connection conn = null;
            PreparedStatement sth = null;
            ResultSet rs =null;
            try {
                conn = delegate.getConnection();
                sth = conn.prepareStatement(INSERT_SQL);
                sth.setString(1, pais.getNombre());
                sth.executeUpdate();
                rs=sth.getGeneratedKeys();
                if(rs.next()){
                    Integer id = (Integer) rs.getInt(1);
                    pais.setId(id);
                }
            }
```

with `,Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);"` no found.

Answer (score 0):

Use that simple code:

```
// Do your insert code

myDataBase.execSQL("INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (FIELD_NAME1,FIELD_NAME2,...)VALUES (VALUE1,VALUE2,...)");

// Use the sqlite function "last_insert_rowid"

Cursor last_id_inserted = yourBD.rawQuery("SELECT last_insert_rowid()", null);

// Retrieve data from cursor.

last_id_inserted.moveToFirst(); // Don't forget that!

ultimo_id = last_id_inserted.getLong(0);  // For Java, the result is returned on Long type  (64)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a transaction you can use `SELECT lastval()` after an insert to get the last generated id.