# error: column "user_account_id_seq" does not exist after insert in postgresql

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, insert, sequence

I am trying to [retrieve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241003/how-to-get-a-value-from-the-last-inserted-row) the ID value of an inserted row using node.js' pg module. The query is:

```
INSERT INTO "MySchema"."USER_ACCOUNT"
  ("LANG","NAME","EMAIL","EMAIL_CONF","STATUS","STATUS_UPDATE","CREATION","PREFERENCES")
  VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8)
  RETURNING USER_ACCOUNT_ID_seq;
```

But I get the following error message:

```
Cannot insert user account { [error: column "user_account_id_seq" does not exist]...
```

I don't provide an id, because I am letting the database set the next sequence value.

How can I retrieve this ID value after the insert? Thanks!

Comment: Although the ID is generated by the sequence, you could retrieve it from the linked column, probably called "ID" in this case, e.g. `... RETURNING "ID";`

Comment: Arrrrrrgh, I am gonna kick myself baaad. I had tried with ID, without the "" and it did not work. A simple syntax error... If you create the solution I'll approve it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the ID is generated by the sequence, you could retrieve it from the linked column, probably called "ID" in this case, e.g. `... RETURNING "ID";`.

["How do I get the value of a SERIAL insert?"](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#How_do_I_get_the_value_of_a_SERIAL_insert.3F)