# How to retrieve the current ID of sequence without using seq.currval

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle

i need last id that insert into persons for some manipulation in java.
I have two insert then if I use getGeneratedKeys I get “operation not allowed” error. I use a select query to retrieve current value of sequence but it cause “an into clause is expected” error. How could I manage to access to last person id.
The query:

```
    begin
        insert into Persons  
           (Id,First_Name,Last_Name)  
           values (person_seq.nextval  ,?  ,?  );
        insert into Relations (relation_id, person_id) 
            values (relation_seq.nextval,person_seq.currval); 
        SELECT person_seq.currval FROM DUAL;
    end;
```

the java code:

```
    stmt = connectionManager.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);//,new String[] {"ID"});
    stmt.setString(1, family.getFName());
    stmt.setString(2, family.getLName());
    ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery();
    ret = resultSet.getLong(1);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a value from the last inserted row?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241003/how-to-get-a-value-from-the-last-inserted-row)

Comment: i have 2 insert in this query. then i cant use generated key and when i use Returning i got error and i cant fetch what it return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare a variable to store the new id with RETURNING INTO clause:

```
declare
   new_id number; --or your id row type
begin
        insert into Persons  
           (Id,First_Name,Last_Name)  
           values (person_seq.nextval  ,?  ,?  )
           returning id into new_id;
        insert into Relations (relation_id, person_id) 
            values (relation_seq.nextval,person_seq.currval); 
end;
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. how i can access new_id in java code i use executeQuery and get error "Cannot perform fetch on a PLSQL statement: next"

Comment: I haven't used java for a while, but see if this answer helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915166/how-to-get-the-insert-id-in-jdbc?lq=1