# Using variables in SQL script

Tags: postgresql

I am writing a unit test for my PostgreSQL functionality. This starts with inserting data in the database and then calling a certain function. However, because I use auto-incrementing IDs, I cannot know what parameter to put in my function call.

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO myTable ...;

SELECT id FROM myTable INTO l_id;

SELECT my_function(l_id);
```

**Updates**

- I am using an SQL script, not PL/pgSQL
- In MySQL I can do this: `SELECT @id:=itemid FROM myTable;`, then later on, I can use `@id` anywhere I like.

Comment: If you are using Java: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241003/how-to-get-a-value-from-the-last-inserted-row
Ensure that you are using a JDBC 4 driver.

Comment: The problem isn't getting the last ID (there is only one, so no problem there). The problem is how to `SELECT` a value and use it later in the script.

Comment: Store it into a results table and retrieve it when you need it?

Comment: @wildplasser how do I retrieve it, to use them in the `SELECT my_function()` call?

Comment: @BartFriederichs : see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DROP SCHEMA tmp CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA tmp ;
SET search_path=tmp;

CREATE TABLE mytab
    ( id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    );
INSERT INTO mytab (id) SELECT gs FROM generate_series(1,10) gs;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tmp.myfunc ( _int  integer )
RETURNS text AS
$func$

DECLARE ret text;

BEGIN
    ret = 'OMG_' || _int::text;
RETURN ret;
END;
$func$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    ;

SELECT myfunc(1);

SELECT myfunc(mt.id)
FROM mytab mt
    ;
```

Also, for smaller things you could use psql's `\gset` command :  [(link to documentation)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-psql.html)

Comment: Of course, as simple as `SELECT myFun(id) FROM table`. Should have thought of that myself.

Answer (score 1):

[INSERT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-insert.html) in Postgres returns an OID, which you can get in a number of ways

- Using the returning clause in normal SQL, e.g.

`INSERT INTO distributors (did, dname) VALUES (DEFAULT, 'XYZ Widgets')
     RETURNING did;`

- using the [GET DIAGNOSTICS](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/plpgsql-statements.html) api in PL-PGSQL
- using the return function in a helper library (syntax depending on library).

In your case, you could do something like

```
with res as (
INSERT INTO my_table (id, ...) VALUES(x,..)
RETURNING id)
SELECT my_function(res.id);
```

Comment: I am using a simple SQL script, no libraries, just something along the line of `psql < test.sql`.

Comment: OK, have clarified the answer

Comment: Okay, and how can I use that `did` in my function call? In a plain SQL script? MySQL for example has `@` for variables.

Comment: I found a solution using a `DO` block, which works fine as well (seems to be some kind of anonymous function)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75142/postgresql-equivalent-of-mysql-query-variables) I found mentioning of the [`DO`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-do.html) block, which seems to work as a anonymous function. I fixed it like this:

```
INSERT ...

DO $$
DECLARE
    l_id integer;
BEGIN
    SELECT id FROM table INTO l_id;
    SELECT myFunction(l_id);
END$$;
```