# How to get a field value, which is default to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, in an insert statement in MySQL with Mybatis

Tags: mysql, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I have a table in MySQL as below:

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `phone` VARCHAR(128) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `createTime` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=25
;
```

I have a Mybatis mapper as below

```
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {
    Integer insertRecord(List<PhoneModel> list);
}


<insert id="insertRecord" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyProperty="id" keyColumn="id">
    insert into mytable(phone) values
    <foreach item="item" index="index" collection="list" separator=",">
        (#{item.phone})
    </foreach>
</insert>
```

There are three properites in `PhoneModel`: `id`,`phone`,`createTime`. Now I can get `id` after calling `insertRecord`, but I want to get `createTime` as well.

I've gone through the [documents](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#insert_update_and_delete) on Mybatis. It mentions that I can add multiple property names (such as `createTime`) to `keyProperty` and `keyColumn`.

> keyProperty   (insert and update only) Identifies a property into which MyBatis will set the key value returned by getGeneratedKeys, or by a selectKey child element of the insert statement. Default: unset. Can be **a comma separated list of property names** if multiple generated columns are expected.
>
> keyColumn (insert and update only) Sets the name of the column in the table with a generated key. This is only required in certain databases (like PostgreSQL) when the key column is not the first column in the table. Can be **a comma separated list of columns names** if multiple generated columns are expected.

I'm not clear about what **a comma separated list of property/column names** means. I've tried keyProperty="id, createTime" but it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If `keyProperty="id, createTime"` is a copy from your code, then clear the space after the comma. It might not be the (only) culprit anyway.

I guess the auto_increment internally operates like a sequence. Whereas CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is a function.
Then you may check the multiple keyProperty  support behavior: for test purpose, can you add another column (auto_increment , serial ?) so that you check you can get generated keys.

It seems [PostgreSQL allows RETURNING](https://stackoverflow.com/a/241242/7076047) value from an Insert, but I' have not found equivalent in MySQL.

You execute a single multi row insert statement, how the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP behaves? exactly the same timestamp is inserted for all records? or the values evolves? this can be observed when inserting a large number of record, that will take more than 1 second.

An why not inserting the timestamp yourself? just bulk insert instead of multi row insert, iterate the list in the java, the session must use an `ExecutorTYPE.REUSE` to prepare the statement only once.

```
for(PhoneModel model : list) {
    model.setCreateTime(new Date());
    mapper.insertRecord(model);
}
```